# Date compare If statement not working, see what is wrong

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to compare two dates and see what is similar but the `if` doesn't 
  work. I want to create a comparison with a cell value and a column of values.

```
function jobLogSchedule () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();/// Activate Sheet Application
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var dataBase = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet  
  var viewSchedule = formSS.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var firstDate = new Date(viewSchedule);
  formSS.getRange("H2").setValue(firstDate);
  formSS.getRange("H4").setValue(firstDate);
  var lastRow = dataBase.getLastRow();
  for(i=1; i<lastRow; i++){
    var workingCell = dataBase.getRange(i,6,lastRow);
    var dateDataBase = workingCell.getValue();
    if (dateDataBase == viewSchedule) {

    }
    else {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/7108653

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function jobLogSchedule () {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fsh=ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName("Data");  
  var lastRow=dsh.getLastRow();
  var drg=dsh.getRange(1,6,lastRow,1);
  var vA=drg.getValues();
  var firstDate = new Date(fsh.getRange("H2").getValue());
  fsh.getRange("H2").setValue(firstDate);
  fsh.getRange("H4").setValue(firstDate);  
  for(i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if (new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf()==firstDate.valueOf()) {
      //true
    }
    else {
      //false
    } 
  }
}
```